# Phase versus time graph of QPSK

Tags: digital-communications, qpsk, constellation-diagram

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying), there was an example on QPSK modulation where the main signal was `11000110` and *I* contained `1001` and *Q* contained `1010`, now their output was shown by the *Signal* in the figure.

[image: Time diagram of QPSK]

Now according to constellation diagram *Signal* can be represented as

```
11 -> pi/4                           
00 -> -(3*pi)/4                           
01 -> (3*pi)/4                            
10 -> -pi/4
```

[image]

But my confusion was in the *phase vs time diagram* shown in another figure given below

[image]

For `11` it starts from phase *pi/4*, but for `00` shouldn't the phase start from *-(3*pi)/4 = -135* ?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Are these diagrams linked? The mapping of bit groups to constellation points is arbitrary (in reality, *gray coding* puts a restriction to arbitrarity).

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the phase plot doesn't match the signal plot. Note that it also shows more symbols than the signal plot. Those two plots do not refer to the same bit sequence, and the phase plot is only meant to illustrate the difference between QPSK and OQPSK (the [original figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#/media/File:Oqpsk_phase_plot.svg) consists of two plots, one for QPSK and one for OQPSK).